# How to replace a icon/image onclick of a link in html using css or angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular6

My code is given below,

```
  <ul style="list-style:none">
        <li><i class="fa fa-hospital-o first" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">arrows</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">battery</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">bell</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-industry" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">bicycle</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">circle</a></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#">deaf</a></li>
    </ul>
```

So, onclick of a link I need to change the color of content & icon in the link.

css:

```
ul li:active {
 color:green;
}
```

It is not working. When selecting a particular list item, I need to change the color. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: For clear code , first embded **i** tag inside the **a** tag and then add `.active` selector for **a** tag !!

Comment: @KrDjamel  thanks for your reply. My question is after selecting a particular list item how to make that look like selected. I mean how to change the css & font-icon once the list item got selected? Could you please help me?

Comment: i post a solution check it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution hope it will help :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("ul > li").click(function(){
      $("ul > li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative; 
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

li.active a {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hospital first" aria-hidden="true"></i>arrows</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>battery</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>bell</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-industry" aria-hidden="true"></i>bicycle</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i>circle</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>deaf</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got i as item ? thats weird but w/e i also dont get what you want a list but w/e

```
<ul>
<li><a class="something" href="#">arrows</a></li>
</ul>

.something:active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

again i dont get the question, or what your asking it seems your marking way to much on html, you need to clean your code

Comment: you could also use just a div with a class to change everything inside that div https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: That was a typo. sorry. On clicking the link I need to change the color of the font-awesome icon & the name of the link. Can you please help me ?

Comment: i cannot see the icon in your code heres an example lets say you got everything on a div

<div class="items"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">arrows</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

so in css you will do something like this

.items, a:activer {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: orangered;
}

But you need to read the active condition you can see it working with hover

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: i cannot see the icon in your code heres an example lets say you got everything on a div
[code]
<div class="items"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#">arrows</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

so in css you will do something like this

a:active {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: orangered;
}

you can also trigger .img:active {}
[/code]
But you need to read the active condition you can see it working with hover

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

didnt allow me to edit it lol